# Angular Google Charts - Auto Height

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, angular-chart

im using this plugin.

> https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart

And i need help to define **Auto Height** with type BarChart.
When get too big,  I use scroll.

Thank you very much!

Comment: try something like that:
`$scope.topDez.options = {
'title': '',
'legend' : {'position': 'bottom'},
height: topDez_descricao.length * 40
};`

Answer (score 1):

the chart will automatically fill the containing `<div>`

use css to style the `<div>`

and lose any *specific* `height` or `width` config options on the chart

on `resize`, the chart will need to be redrawn

although the following example is not angular, the chart will behave the same

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'Month', type: 'string'},
        {label: 'Amount', type: 'number'},
        {role: 'style', type: 'string'}
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: 'April'}, {v: 12}, {v: '#c62828'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'May'}, {v: 10}, {v: '#ad1457'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'June'}, {v: 8}, {v: '#6a1b9a'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'July'}, {v: 6}, {v: '#4527a0'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'August'}, {v: 4}, {v: '#283593'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'September'}, {v: 2}, {v: '#1565c0'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'October'}, {v: 2}, {v: '#00838f'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'November'}, {v: 4}, {v: '#00695c'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'December'}, {v: 6}, {v: '#2e7d32'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'January'}, {v: 8}, {v: '#9e9d24'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'February'}, {v: 10}, {v: '#f9a825'}]},
        {c:[{v: 'March'}, {v: 12}, {v: '#d84315'}]}
      ]
    });

    var options = {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      legend: 'none',
      theme: 'maximized'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);

    $(window).resize(function() {
      chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
}

.mainBody {
  background-color: yellow;
  bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div class="header" >&nbsp;</div>
<div class="mainBody" id="chart_div"></div>
<div class="footer">&nbsp;</div>
```